# Jquery filter select boxes divs

Tags: jquery, filter

I'm trying to create a "Jobs" filter
which will filter jobs based on **Location** and **Departments**

First I display all jobs divided by the departments like so:

- Department
  -- Job
  -- Job
  -- Job
- Department
  -- Job
  -- Job
  -- Job

And then I want the to filter them with 2 drio down select boxes
using simple Jquery and CSS only

Also added "No Results" option which wil show when there is no combination

I think I am very close but still it doesn't work perfectly with all
the combinations. think I am missing something

```
$("select#locations").change(function() {
  // Get selected option value from dropdown
  let location = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  let careerBox = $(".career-box");
  // $(".department").removeClass("hide");
  let departmentTitle = $(".department-title");
  // console.log(location);
  // Remove all selected classes first
  careerBox.removeClass("show");
  careerBox.removeClass("hide");
  $(".locations span").removeClass("selected");
  // Add selected class to selected location
  $('.locations span[data-location="' + location + '"]').addClass("selected");
  careerBox.each(function() {
    if (location != "all-locations") {
      // departmentTitle.addClass("hide");
      if ($(this).find(".locations span").hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).addClass("show");
        departmentTitle.addClass("hide");
        $(this).siblings(".department-title").removeClass("hide");
        // $(this).siblings(departmentTitle).addClass("show");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("hide");
      }
    } else {
      departmentTitle.removeClass("hide");
    }
  });
  // $(".filter select#departments").val("all-departments").trigger("change");
  // console.log($(".all-careers").height());
  if ($(".all-careers").height() > 1) {
    $(".no-results").removeClass("show");
  } else {
    $(".no-results").addClass("show");
  }
});



// Departments
$("#departments").change(function() {
  // Get selected option value from dropdown
  let departmentType = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  // console.log(departmentType);
  let departmentBox = $(".department");
  $(".department").removeClass("selected").removeClass("show");
  $(".department").addClass("hide");

  departmentBox.each(function() {
    if (departmentType != "all-departments") {
      $('.department[data-department="' + departmentType + '"]').addClass(
        "selected show"
      );
      $('.department[data-department="' + departmentType + '"]').removeClass(
        "hide"
      );
    } else {
      $(".department")
        .removeClass("selected")
        .removeClass("show")
        .removeClass("hide");
    }
  });
  // No results
  // $(".filter select#locations").val("all-locations").trigger("change");
  // console.log($(".all-careers").height());
  if ($(".all-careers").height() > 1) {
    $(".no-results").removeClass("show");
  } else {
    $(".no-results").addClass("show");
  }
});
```

here is an almost finished fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/hamergil/x2b8s6mv/82/

If anyone can help make it work perfectly
Id appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What do you mean when you say it doesn't work perfectly?

Comment: Try to choose Israel for instance.. Yuo will see that the first heading is getting class of "hide" you need to inspect the code to see it... "Customer Success and Tech Ops" is missing. it should always display the titles when jobs are associated with them

Answer (score 0):

You can check if under `department` there is `selected` class and `length > 0` if yes then use `addClass("show")` to show the title of department else hide whole `department` div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#locations").select2({
  width: "resolve",
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
});

$("#departments").select2({
  width: "resolve",
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
});



$("select#locations").change(function() {
  // Get selected option value from dropdown
  let location = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  let careerBox = $(".career-box");
  $(".department").removeClass("hide"); //hide the title
  let departmentTitle = $(".department-title");
  // Remove all selected classes first
  careerBox.removeClass("show");
  careerBox.removeClass("hide");
  $(".locations span").removeClass("selected");
  // Add selected class to selected location
  $('.locations span[data-location="' + location + '"]').addClass("selected");
  if (location != "all-locations") {
    careerBox.each(function() {

      if ($(this).find(".locations span").hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).addClass("show");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("hide");
      }
      //check if the length of slected inside department is > 0
      if ($(this).closest(".department").find(".locations .selected").length > 0) {
        //show the title
        $(this).closest(".department-title").addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
      } else {
        //hide that div 
        $(this).closest(".department").addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
      }
    });
  } else {
    departmentTitle.removeClass("hide");
  }
  if ($(".all-careers").height() > 1) {
    $(".no-results").removeClass("show");
  } else {
    $(".no-results").addClass("show");
  }
});
```

```css
.all-careers h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.all-careers .career-box .heading {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #16063d;
}

.all-careers .career-box.show {
  display: block;
}

.all-careers .career-box.hide {
  display: none;
}

.all-careers .department .department-title.hide {
  display: none;
}

.all-careers .department.hide {
  display: none;
}

.all-careers .no-results.show {
  display: block;
}

.all-careers .career-box .wrap-info {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.no-results {
  display: none;
}

.department-title {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <select id="locations">
        <option value="all-locations">All Locations</option>
        <option value="brazil">Brazil</option>
        <option value="israel">Israel</option>
        <option value="new-jersey">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="romania">Romania</option>
        <option value="singapore">Singapore</option>
        <option value="texas">Texas</option>
      </select>

      <select id="departments">
        <option value="all-departments">All Departments</option>
        <option value="customer-success-and-tech-ops">Customer Success and Tech Ops</option>
        <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
        <option value="product-management">Product Management</option>
        <option value="rd-and-engineering">R&D and Engineering</option>
        <option value="sales">Sales</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="all-careers">
        <div class="no-results">No Results</div>
        <div class="department" data-department="customer-success-and-tech-ops">
          <div class="department-title">Customer Success and Tech Ops</div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>CS Production Engineer</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="israel">Israel</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>Program Manager</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="texas">Texas</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>SRE (Site Reliability Engineer)</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="israel">Israel</span><span data-location="new-jersey">New Jersey</span><span data-location="texas">Texas</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>Junior PMO</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="israel">Israel</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>Optimization Expert</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="israel">Israel</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>PMO</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="israel">Israel</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>RAN Automation Delivery Expert</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="new-jersey">New Jersey</span><span data-location="texas">Texas</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="department" data-department="marketing">
          <div class="department-title">Marketing</div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>Product Marketing&nbsp;Manager</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="israel">Israel</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>Field Marketing Manager</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="new-jersey">New Jersey</span><span data-location="singapore">Singapore</span><span data-location="texas">Texas</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="department" data-department="product-management">
          <div class="department-title">Product Management</div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>Product Expert</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="romania">Romania</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="department" data-department="rd-and-engineering">
          <div class="department-title">R&amp;D and Engineering</div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>Quality Assurance (QA) Manager</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="israel">Israel</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>Senior Java Developer</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="israel">Israel</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="department" data-department="sales">
          <div class="department-title">Sales</div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>Business Development Director</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="new-jersey">New Jersey</span><span data-location="texas">Texas</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="career-box">
            <div class="heading d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="wrap-info">
                <a href="#">
                  <h2>Regional Sales Director</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="locations"><span data-location="brazil">Brazil</span></div>
              </div><a id="career-btn" class="orange-btn" href="#">Apply</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```